# Using jQuery to build a link that can be copied and shared

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I am trying to create a utility to help mobile users share a YouTube link and have it start at a specified time (YouTube does not offer this feature in their mobile website and apps).

The user pastes their link:

e.g. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHcQy8jdAGY`

They can then add values into the hour, minute and second fields.

As they do so, the final link is being built for them to copy and share.

The final link will look something like this:

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHcQy8jdAGY&t=1h1m1s`

...and thus the video will start at the 1:01:01 mark.

I have begun to build my utility in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/stevland/pen/xxWZVXb).

What I can't figure out is how to append the TIME values — if and when they are added by the user — to the URL field.

When a value is added to *any* of the fields, the `&t=` part of the URL needs to be appended first.

And although it doesn't matter what order the h/m/s values appear in the URL, it would be nice to keep them in order.

BTW I am a total hack, but I can usually muddle my way through these things eventually (with a little help).

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Use the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and the [searchparams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and the [searchparams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```js
const $urlField = $('input[name=URL]');
$('#container').on('input', function() {
  let url;
  try {
    url = new URL($("#link").val());
  }
  catch {
    $urlField.val("Please paste a valid URL")
    return
  }
  let [h, m, s] = $("#time-wrap input").map(function() {
    return this.value.trim()
  }).get()
  let time = "";
  time += h ? `${h}h` : "";
  time += m ? `${m}m` : "";
  time += s ? `${s}s` : "";
  url.searchParams.set("t",time)
  console.log(time,url.toString())
  $urlField.val(url.toString());
});
```

```css
[name=URL] {
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <input id="link" type="url" placeholder="Paste the link to your video">

  <div id="time-wrap">
    <input placeholder="Hour">
    <input placeholder="Minute">
    <input placeholder="Second">
  </div>

  <input type="text" id="result-field" name="URL" placeholder="" value="Your sharing link will appear here">
  <br />
</div>
<button onclick="copyFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. A free web utility is now available to the world with your contribution: https://yttimestamp.com/

Comment: Please consider having a peek at my next question related to this project:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72890299/get-text-field-and-use-it-to-build-a-facebook-sharing-link)

Comment: @stevland I gave you an answer in that other question. I think it is better than what you accepted