# Get text field and use it to build a Facebook sharing link

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am building a free utility to help mobile users share a YouTube video with a manually configured start time (YouTube does not offer this feature in their mobile website and apps).

The user pastes the link to the video and then configures the start time.

They can then copy the link to their clipboard. I have this working, with some help.

https://yttimestamp.com/

I am using this code for the copy function:

```
function copyFunction() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("result-field");
  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */
  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
}
```

My next task is to create a Facebook sharing link.

It should similarly grab the current value of the `"result-field"` (a URL), only in this case it will generate a clickable button with an href tag that looks like this:

[https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="](https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=%22) + "URL"

I imagine the resulting URL will be inserted into the following link, although perhaps I can't foresee how this function needs to be implemented as I am only a hack.

```
<a onclick="facebookFunction()" target="_self" href="">
<img src="img/Facebook.svg" alt="Share to Facebook"/></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default I'm hiding the link since it will not have a HREF on load. Then I set the HREF using setAttribute by calling the link by a class.

Then I have a class called active that is added to the link to display the link.

For my answer I removed your image, but you can add that back in.

```js
function copyFunction() {
  let fbShare = document.querySelector(".facebook-share");
  fbShare.classList.remove("active");
  
  var copyText = document.getElementById("result-field");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
  
  fbShare.setAttribute("href","https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + copyText.value);
  fbShare.classList.add("active");
}

copyFunction()
```

```css
.facebook-share{display:none;}
.facebook-share.active{display:block;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="result-field" value="https://stackoverflow.com/">


<a target="_self" href="" target="_blank" class="facebook-share">Share on Facebook</a>
```

Comment: I added this code to https://yttimestamp.com/ as a link for now. It _almost_ works! But it is grabbing the default value of `result-field` ("Your sharing link will appear here"), rather than the current value. Thus no matter what the input is, the generated link looks like this: `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=Your%20sharing%20link%20will%20appear%20here`

Comment: Nevermind. It's sorted. Thank you for your help.

Comment: OP does not need the link in the clipboard since it is likely already in the clipboard. OP just wanted a link. Your code runs before the user can update the input field

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that tests the link is valid

```js
const shareLink = new URL("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php")
const fbLink = document.getElementById("facebook-link");
const linkField = document.getElementById("result-field");
document.getElementById("result-field").addEventListener("input", function() {
  fbLink.hidden = true;
  const link = linkField.value;
  try {
    const url = new URL(link); // may fail
    shareLink.searchParams.set("u", url.toString());
    fbLink.setAttribute("href", shareLink.toString());
    fbLink.hidden = false;
  } catch {
    // ...
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="result-field" value="" placeholder="Your link here">
<a href="" target="_blank" id="facebook-link" hidden>Share on Facebook</a>
```